# Importing labels into existing data labelling project fails

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines

I'm encountering an issue with the Azure Machine Learning (Azure ML) service, specifically with importing labels into an existing data labeling project. Despite ensuring the format of the imported labels matches the expected schema, none of the parsed labels appear to be imported into the project.

What I've tried:

- I've exported the labeled data from the labeling project to understand the expected format.
- Created a data asset matching the exported format with columns such as image_url, label, label_confidence, labeler, updated_by, approved_by, labeling_time_in_seconds, label_creation_time, image_height, image_width, and image_details.
- I used the import labels feature, importing from an azure ML data asset.
- The UI correctly identifies the data mapping [see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4gLC.png)
- UI reports that it succesfully imported the labels, but none of the labels are imported.  [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRaUW.png)
- No datapoints imported, skipped or rejected